# Array values not being processed

Tags: php, mysql

I put together some code to process the values in an array. However, it appears that only the first line is being printed out. I can verify that the array has a size of 247 (by including a `sizeof()` check before the loop).

Is there something I am not seeing here? The declaration of my `$title` variable is :

```
$title = array();
```

on a global scope.

```
function pushTitleChanges()
{
  global $title, $first_name, $last_name;
  $index = 0;

  print_r($title);
  if(is_array($title))
  {
    for($x =0; $x< sizeof($title);$x++)
    {
        echo "The index is " . $index .' '. "and title size is " . sizeof($title);
        echo "<br/>";

        $title = str_replace(array('.', ','), '' , $title[$index]);

        $statement = "UPDATE guest_list_guests
        SET guest_list_guests.title = '{$title}'
        WHERE guest_list_guests.first_name ='{$first_name[$index]}'
        AND guest_list_guests.last_name = '{$last_name[$index]}';";
        $index++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the entire title array to `str_replace(array('.', ','), '' , $title[$index]);'  This is overwriting the entire array with a String when it seems you want to only change that index.  Hence that line would really be:

```
 $title[$index] = str_replace(array('.', ','), '' , $title[$index]);
```

I also recommend using the `$x` variable you have created, it stores the same value as `$index` making `$index` completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that I see this what it was, I feel really embarrassed, haha.